# How to keep or add quotation marks in dynamic content (Azure Data Factory) without escape characters being added?

Tags: xml, azure, escaping, azure-data-factory

I have a third party API I need to call in a copy activity in Data Factory. I use dynamic content for the request body, because i need one field to be the output of a prior lookup in the pipeline.

The part of the request body needs to look like this:

< Filter>[List]="536,323,235,674"< /Filter>

The problem is that the request body needs the quotation marks to work, and i cannot run it without escape characters being added automatically. The value of the list comes from a lookup activity in an SQL database, so my dynamic request body looks like this:

< Filter>[List]=',activity('Lookup1').output.value.list,'< /Filter>

*Where
activity('Lookup1').output.value.list = "536,323,235,674"
**OR**
activity('Lookup1').output.value.list = 536,323,235,674*

I've tried different variations of working around the escape characters using '\"' and similar. I've also tried with functions such as substring and replace to prevent the request body to add escape characters, but nothing works.

The input of the copy data activity always comes out like this:
< Filter>[List]=\"536,323,235,674\"< /Filter>

How can i prevent these backslashes?

I really appreciate any help here.

Picture steps:

[I can edit my query to retrieve the exact string i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYcNn.png)

[When i click preview data, it looks perfect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSqdH.png)

[However, the lookup activity adds backslashes in the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBLFN.png)

[And so my output looks like this, and is useless in the copy data activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kL5o.png)

I don't know, but it looks to me like i cannot fix this issue in the lookup-activity, but rather have to do it in the dynamic content field of the request body. Not sure of course, im pretty new to data factory

Comment: One easy workaround would be for your lookup to return the exact string you want, formatted exactly as you need.  If you want to continue pursuing the formatting in ADF, however, then can you please post screenshots?  It's not quite clear how things are set up in the ADF editor.

Comment: Thank you, JeffRamos! Im not able to post pictures in these comments, so i will just edit my first questions here.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character,I've also tried several times to remove it but not able to do that. Does this `< Filter>[List]='536,323,235,67'< /Filter>` work?  Is single quotes feasible?

Comment: Thanks Joseph Xu! Unfortunately it is not, the list of values has to come in quotation marks for the xml to read it... I've tried several other ways to filter to retrieve the data that i need, but it is not possible - and as i said, its third party, so i just have to find some way around it

Comment: I‘ve tried several times, but not able to do that. I think we should send a feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes. I've posted this in Microsofts Q&A now, so I hope they can help me resolve it. I have found similar questions on other forums including Microsoft, but no solution was ever published.

Comment: Hello @BrNyh, hope things going well. It may take a long time to fix this issue. May I  post it(sent a feedback to Microsoft, waiting for reply) as answer? Then your post won't be closed. After get response from MS we can add it to the answer.

Comment: Hello @BrNyh, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In string type, Azure data factory will add '\' to escape double quotes, we've tried several ways to remove it but failed.Now we've posted this issue in Microsofts Q&A and we are waiting for reply.